# Converting rtsp stream to bmp images

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, rtsp, bmp, dib

I have a requirement in which I have to convert a RTSP video stream into BMP images and then pass on to my face detection application. 
So is it possible to do the same using ffmpeg tool? If not, then can anybody guide me to the right tool/some custom code which does the same.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [image2](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) muxer:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i <rtsp stream> -f image2 'img-%03d.bmp'
```

Comment: The `-f image2` isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, unless the output name is not explicitly named such as in a script.